# Does it saves battery when we stop using GPS in android

Tags: android, gps

In my android app, i want to TurnOFF GPS once app closes, but it is not possible for android 4.x devices.So if we stop using GPS, whenever it is not neccessary "like person is in same place from last few hours", but GPS is always ON in mobile, then does it consume same battery power as  when we are using GPS like "when person is moving"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate between GPS is on/off and application uses/doesn't use GPS. Most users keep GPS on all the time on their devices. This is just a permission allowing applications to use GPS whenever they want. As long as applications don't actively use GPS, the GPS hardware unit is still off. When application registers a location listener at [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), then Android switches GPS unit on. User will see "GPS active" icon in the right corner of status bar. If user sees this icon, then it means location will be detected and GPS consumes power.

Another aspect to consider is, which location provider is used. If you use "gps" location provider, then you will get most accurate position, but battery consumption will be the highest. If you use "network" provider, then position will be not that accurate, but power consumption will be much less.

*Answering your question.* If you unregister location listener in your app, the app will definitely help to save battery. You do not need to switch GPS off for that.

Comment: Can we unregister location listener at LocationManager when user is same postion for more than specfic time, again once again we register location listener when person startsmoving?

Comment: There is no such function out of box, but you can try to use Google Play Services for this: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether having GPS on while not moving, and having it on while on the move use the same amount of battery, the answer is yes.  As long as GPS is on it will check locations no matter whether the person is moving or not.

Comment: oh thanks, is there any way to save battery when app is not running which uses gps?

Answer (score 0):

I don't disagree with the answer that beworker gave but I think there is a better answer. And the better answer is to use the new google play location services. It is much easier to use and is much more accurate. You no longer need to worry about which provider to use.

All you do is tell is create a locationRequest object, tell it what accuracy you want and what time interval or distance traveled parameter you want and it figures out which provider to use itself and also works to minimize battery usage. It really makes sense to go with google play now. So much better. I have a full working sample here:

https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker/tree/master/phoneClients/android